# How to download several photos from the server at once?

Tags: c#

I have a code that downloads one image from the link, is it possible to make it so that all image of the format are downloaded from the link .png

```
 var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://31.44.65.47:5240/9. logo.png");

 using (var response = request.GetResponse())
 using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
 {
     pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
 }
```

Comment: Either make a zip with images on the server side and download them as a single archive, or have a list of links on the client and process them via loop.

Comment: Do several https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-webrequest-getresponseasync and combine with a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0